# How to change format of XAMPP reported PHP-error (in HTML)?

Tags: php, xampp

I want to change XAMPP generated error from (full-HTML-formatted) to (simple-formatted-error), such as:
this:

```
<br />
<font size='1'>
    <table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
        <tr>
            <th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5">
                <span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined index: act in D:\Z_web_prj\htdocs\mb\t_act.php on line
                <i>3</i>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th>
            <th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th>
            <th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th>
            <th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th>
            <th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td>
            <td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.4033</td>
            <td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>364704</td>
            <td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td>
            <td title='D:\Z_web_prj\htdocs\mb\t_act.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>...\t_act.php
                <b>:</b>0
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</font>
```

> [image]

into simpler formatting (similar to error reported from Live Apache hosting)

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: act in
<b>/home/user/public_html/kalivolumerootxyz/t_act.php</b> on line
<b>3</b>
<br />
```

> [image]

It is too much annoyed with big red banner boom on screen even it is just a **NOTICES**. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's PHP setting [`html_errors`](http://php.net/html-errors). Set it to `html_errors=0` to show errors as plain text. Don't forget to restart PHP services

Comment: you meant "html_errors" in configuration file "php.ini".